# Scalable private message system

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, chat, server-sent-events

My first post on stackoverflow!

I know there is some debate here about this subject but I didn't come to any definitive deciision ( to this specific situation ). So, I have this question ! I'm building a store finder website (php, javascript and mysql based app) and I'm in the final stages so I'm just needing to code the private message and notification system.

Since I'm starting it and I don't have that much cash I'm on shared hosting ( I know... ) and I have to build this notification system the best I can with the resources I have.

I'm using server sent events and I'm thinking of 2 possibilitys :

- storing the last read id in the html code and mysql querying every notification / pm prior it ( to save space ).
- storing the notification / pm id's in a txt file and cleaning the file after read so I don't do many database connections. ( like: if file has numbers written , query those id numbers , else dont do anything ).

So , in your opinion what would you if you'd face my problem? ( my business plan plans on scalling this website to 10.000 users on the first 6 months so I definitivelly have to upgrade the server but until I'm done with the beta tests I'm sticking to SSE and mySQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the idea on the first is to make fast connections 
the idea on the second is to save connections ( because of concurent connections )

Comment: 1. SSE does not scale well over large applications and managing a session chain between an cluster of servers providing SSE's would be insane. 2. Staring a business that will attract tons of clients and planning on migrating during the middle of your "launch" to a new server stack is insane.

Comment: I'm aware of that, ( really aware of that ) but we are facing a situation here, in Portugal we have a total lack of investment and funds, so, me and my team are struggling a lot to get this done. In this phase we invest on the server or on the marketing strategy, as soon as we have something the first thing will be the server. 

Probably I'll close the chat part and make the conversations via email, but at least the notification system has to be working. Our code is as fluid as it can be to avoid those problems but still we have to face this. 

After some intense strategy sessions we came to

Comment: the conclusion that we need to go this way , this is why I was aking for an opinion. 

If we didn't have to do this this way, surelly I would know what to do.